# Am I supposed to always add DoEvents after opening a large Excel file in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some large files that I need to open (but I don't need to write a loop (otherwise, I will definitely go for DoEvents)). These files contain many data and calculations, and possibly many links to be updated (if I opened them manually, I can wait for some time). Then should I add DoEvents whenever I opened a large file as below,

```
Sub Test()
    ...
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Large Workbook.xlsm", 3)
    DoEvents

    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Large Workbook2.xlsm", 3)
    DoEvents
    ....
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. I generally only add DoEvents in processor intensive loops so that, if I need to interrupt the code, I can. It largely is beneficial for preventing Excel from crashing, or for preventing the 'Not Responding' screen.

That said, Excel has it's own way of opening large files. If it truly is a large file, chances are you've seen a download percentage. This is Excel loading and setting up the file.

Generally speaking, if you're getting a whitewashed screen, or Excel is crashing consistently, and you want to get some control back from your application, add a DoEvents command. Otherwise, just let your code do what it needs to do.